# intellisense of vs2017 is slow with boost library and resharper c++ plugin

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, resharper

I use visual studio 2017 for my c++ projects. I am also fan with resharper plugin which has a similar style like Jetbrains Clion.

However, when a **huge** library is included, like Boost C++ Library into projects. The intellisense pops out too slowly, no matter resharper intellisense or vs native intellisense. Furthermore, sometimes vs2017 may misjudge incomplete input as errors for a time.

I have already known some seemly useless method mentioned in official tutorial and my computer is good enough of i7 and high volume memory/ssd no lack of machine performance.

So, anyone can help to increment performance for reshaper c++ in vs2017. Like switch some options like tool or project properties.

Comment: How slow is to slow in your case? 2 seconds? 2 minutes??

Comment: What you can try is cleaning up the resharper cache: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configuring_Caches_Location.html#cleanup

Comment: @xander it's stucked sometimes, not merely slow

Comment: Follow the instructions described here https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207243205 to collect a snapshot and send it to JetBrains team